# Display image next to article

Tags: html, css

My HTML is structured like this: The problem is that the image and each article are displayed in different lines. I tried to float them and to make them display inline, but it did not help

```
<img src="img/sjlk.jpg" /> <!-- Logo -->


    <article>
        <h2>askdfbkansdkn </h2>
        <p>asdhfaksdhfk</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <p>selnlnl sf</p>
        <p>shdfl</p>
        <p>aehfonlknslfn</p>
    </article>
```

I want the image float right to the article without changing the HTML Structure

Thank you!

Comment: The only image displayed is the "logo". Is there an image per article?

Comment: @nunners no, only this one

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? The image displayed on the left and all articles on the right on top of each other?

Comment: Have check the width of your image and articles against the width of your layout which I assume defined in CSS? Could you show your CSS by the way specially the layout. You can use jsfiddle if you like.

Comment: @Edper actually it has no width! Its automatic! 200 px i think! Should i add width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<article>` DIVs.

```
<img src="img/sjlk.jpg" /> <!-- Logo -->
<div class="wrap">
<article>
    <h2>askdfbkansdkn </h2>
    <p>asdhfaksdhfk</p>
</article>
<article>
    <p>selnlnl sf</p>
    <p>shdfl</p>
    <p>aehfonlknslfn</p>
</article> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img, div.wrap {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but does not seem to work! Only my footer is aligned now next to the image

Comment: @John Smith this does work [ http://jsfiddle.net/aXvLP/ ] but perhaps you could show us your code...you didn't mention a footer before.

Comment: This can be done easily if we create a wrapper div and float:left.I hope the the Questioner want exactly not like this

Comment: You must have other CSS conflicting with the code i provided. I'll be happy to take a look if you update your question with the code.